# Which column Combination is Best? - R

Tags: r, combinations

Below is a sample of the data set I'm working with:

```
structure(list(SVM_WinP = c(0.558165671393824, 0.348390523096837, 
0.95493337065313, 0.0388005577521338, 0.736669323790385, 0.168896453268363, 
0.705743689606604, 0.992138145290718, 0.810339570932884, 0.0145257024968556, 
0.541140631037918, 0.437257022506864, 0.739497092250373, 0.625243533966904, 
0.150497415992424, 0.715115299694835, 0.812625896077946, 0.948612041787568, 
0.26448620625025, 0.734515435526053, 0.399712486824722, 0.22554632915551, 
0.0185366382857313, 0.892516918078863, 0.230435327799452, 0.912324570011269, 
0.71628846770974, 0.891120531189591, 0.326028496805855, 0.788864881180649, 
0.585446980301914, 0.656930686507977, 0.811559711972135, 0.422998128997747, 
0.176237445430815, 0.390207772327287, 0.799289216832336, 0.453716951109004, 
0.316937325078128, 0.0975479139041335, 0.212656206249349, 0.727225917796848, 
0.0589924049765094, 0.704428416779042, 0.0651626151496622, 0.935195903907177, 
0.22603403070976, 0.331925528930646, 0.409096405088493, 0.0897325808718911, 
0.0759214065235218, 0.99043710624311, 0.70564387477249, 0.392500549890471, 
0.654295861591396, 0.344903248551428, 0.261717680022946, 0.800187975491863, 
0.640075093428915, 0.0713729699969963, 0.802125102402682, 0.0162662428619326, 
0.675626125667836, 0.729495125292526, 0.562858566153988, 0.866141522104534, 
0.000600272455124062, 0.187123818503705, 0.408661413570358, 0.662178557425881, 
0.967381518793872, 0.378339466187956, 0.383488953847531, 0.82366249439814, 
0.536614974041644, 0.992170654125606, 0.831021118390595, 0.159885205835131, 
0.890692277474385, 0.560003938125708, 0.961825298739267, 0.0838257843353912, 
0.395496873814998, 0.162668110402946, 0.785662879106253, 0.138453575967573, 
0.858532308701443, 0.707366377977707, 0.451099911093265, 0.27160115225865, 
0.453597876327078, 0.646715200637795, 0.446808833127976, 0.394046228758467, 
0.462929523602182, 0.924041526401814, 0.341652286189242, 0.451831445282859, 
0.581440687680135, 0.0925517613786266), Boosted_WinP = c(0.89402261247966, 
0.483670714594616, 0.661212451602682, 0.102014455620411, 0.289828014145476, 
0.0570801901599125, 0.930966558681998, 0.48005474192123, 0.359186789690061, 
0.610737858474027, 0.967551717704477, 0.199246146230633, 0.177721319572841, 
0.577168222508493, 0.886607806421217, 0.634723982886352, 0.976871039022192, 
0.956290271491002, 0.419917349440615, 0.133670577393046, 0.0765556605556079, 
0.237098217108597, 0.979801750731868, 0.672680586055324, 0.725045977926599, 
0.0740428495567435, 0.891159458339062, 0.631750415599141, 0.805786964697526, 
0.962123067571387, 0.621847198501487, 0.196640907520318, 0.707504018539905, 
0.221570092457165, 0.653045678639389, 0.412809228568008, 0.2212228879495, 
0.662859253415819, 0.107905391793683, 0.551955923724445, 0.944560603389602, 
0.988726324659146, 0.649337881350091, 0.900301333510395, 0.724575587263516, 
0.965813952177899, 0.0671322402562242, 0.943316151949797, 0.322598098285156, 
0.449779325602717, 0.020745717658762, 0.26438258954934, 0.374250053005224, 
0.630881056727796, 0.888716928427941, 0.266639380057253, 0.00935638377937442, 
0.0692444468397704, 0.949930917223125, 0.140814337621726, 0.362392597610464, 
0.319108310209083, 0.604714171488092, 0.778562512066814, 0.750863433868021, 
0.405964734099616, 0.689208564147027, 0.305533864346514, 0.414522044813037, 
0.610709181705631, 0.539622473601807, 0.789797808326043, 0.610082648317471, 
0.314523722429576, 0.789090600049371, 0.986978209407206, 0.714937815310679, 
0.104676883555296, 0.901508251093595, 0.719331787482761, 0.738692573763422, 
0.481365914976921, 0.577694538455519, 0.330133430304781, 0.76701513198333, 
0.27169636976014, 0.675104533589495, 0.38758220529306, 0.817665918132103, 
0.224569935842561, 0.137642782903388, 0.38861433169735, 0.340476517281863, 
0.116094571960928, 0.0788352866831896, 0.281260238428684, 0.62599650915352, 
0.955783458828903, 0.929530835778402, 0.10495691432555), PLS_WinP = c(0.39354723733149, 
0.54000675808501, 0.340426806552083, 0.777179557555313, 0.507897688685752, 
0.694818232188098, 0.593846935483312, 0.562915835206265, 0.853709203148761, 
0.0902403931506494, 0.379814264458866, 0.376016855604251, 0.565391931175011, 
0.477586831523071, 0.311687045297573, 0.47364241598787, 0.882997364084817, 
0.460162443155103, 0.776359443552496, 0.600616421729718, 0.0773825441336474, 
0.660293116104677, 0.0590032298475717, 0.245227484789182, 0.94438787432565, 
0.842687663704992, 0.728168466460016, 0.145753700343619, 0.177708509658491, 
0.634430499275636, 0.19966644589498, 0.981134498034763, 0.260532257456577, 
0.56496361314877, 0.156074815970709, 0.216702434267147, 0.936767970703466, 
0.411816552777972, 0.107422857533626, 0.277753722359518, 0.404330137426437, 
0.130127783711268, 0.0104980713589864, 0.377720838386588, 0.133519419340816, 
0.503839507649224, 0.911227329852191, 0.804976040200434, 0.0907083437738657, 
0.734628812113806, 0.403969138559623, 0.644615047897493, 0.68426993586742, 
0.985562440072655, 0.316277451670215, 0.893243089753064, 0.759492030077886, 
0.430715961391847, 0.493800854199238, 0.887996140074659, 0.590165703452082, 
0.775078446791539, 0.404126648856637, 0.17202190853721, 0.426679975602619, 
0.0189556454712428, 0.725679596128594, 0.940800226706401, 0.794246618869053, 
0.588497639101467, 0.826495931466981, 0.298463345807837, 0.0406542203871959, 
0.588265033534172, 0.518999127258825, 0.719442596652878, 0.992038770408227, 
0.0033195080311974, 0.992165758916786, 0.546313016904328, 0.776291901701705, 
0.118868135467985, 0.974025520272049, 0.218512787136481, 0.63449371251762, 
0.817003158588241, 0.861062799577631, 0.735049339627781, 0.178070722335702, 
0.200975229673079, 0.465401012160916, 0.763034561748005, 0.145932817290429, 
0.768996313890048, 0.125020279707435, 0.386656887551852, 0.275941268064707, 
0.750641840531497, 0.840421843079901, 0.287144353270468), LR_WinP = c(0.262697012518672, 
0.417511140329806, 0.667146472801859, 0.762697854238976, 0.389722735583148, 
0.769038676622114, 0.630779526927904, 0.880964844549245, 0.933629831329103, 
0.0729199623950939, 0.189643700519897, 0.671188506222618, 0.640887866294401, 
0.738209297814263, 0.479252798503006, 0.092371444294318, 0.791149416899593, 
0.183032329838997, 0.0528440179102034, 0.713347182772784, 0.542136778846393, 
0.681831696079813, 0.195373846257483, 0.943155177669363, 0.941368682433923, 
0.310042041144368, 0.345805650366193, 0.155234872569669, 0.0403703846871454, 
0.196127468986564, 0.494958482900134, 0.414731832661525, 0.776416544626071, 
0.124761024471987, 0.761069813681869, 0.144067383397882, 0.469516565531721, 
0.562066251266583, 0.779017109874317, 0.392428193314516, 0.744143376328888, 
0.623046148835947, 0.169308036706163, 0.706430604178061, 0.732834938224122, 
0.502769597540655, 0.473769462148849, 0.222683307247984, 0.27422066894613, 
0.569776289627385, 0.638213824757715, 0.612958021854454, 0.619062017788159, 
0.547975167598928, 0.270106889117638, 0.299689849516908, 0.828034148357673, 
0.860401248280072, 0.867155101493026, 0.580069315267473, 0.547248973530937, 
0.076345470752778, 0.658895826263306, 0.639233259924366, 0.205808774941673, 
0.294023916953547, 0.432868814998754, 0.943489557958723, 0.907515638844483, 
0.828845843273485, 0.850648314796682, 0.288097834753634, 0.671366290547666, 
0.879037251235933, 0.0124827413572859, 0.280493897410629, 0.0162973705316591, 
0.809127046301876, 0.629451067500879, 0.901499283838544, 0.391072669964811, 
0.602852074122138, 0.604805662116713, 0.13735168472145, 0.42220946510903, 
0.950159416430759, 0.780990331247864, 0.253484866387938, 0.507014634599896, 
0.207862903175663, 0.310823586606733, 0.557734792983327, 0.391445114349291, 
0.785370274380705, 0.513497291082603, 0.0303323528945423, 0.140790018934132, 
0.541288508082692, 0.16373642829569, 0.0278380611642626), Cubist_WinP = c(0.241873420019825, 
0.223874146182308, 0.248511146677154, 0.899382173351828, 0.215615774430975, 
0.338073130677165, 0.3284297527255, 0.724296036601866, 0.615232294867287, 
0.824200769438341, 0.190423734271807, 0.940860030686527, 0.995310345365077, 
0.37119648225333, 0.798263037114627, 0.187888050612689, 0.232430041208821, 
0.0719966044560845, 0.369515559234538, 0.825546888953371, 0.526463485504593, 
0.576413871593272, 0.597121262858026, 0.586729568038402, 0.723417581533145, 
0.268487181542246, 0.00469857584664435, 0.885891705923672, 0.407971613428226, 
0.221324631202003, 0.548246510306384, 0.072138700588176, 0.13829208707251, 
0.755757369173496, 0.758708784488404, 0.559532866513871, 0.0446287164588287, 
0.270610514785508, 0.901027762454115, 0.845730039486019, 0.810239868959125, 
0.394014868798588, 0.767246370744583, 0.20191425809665, 0.519366898808556, 
0.585299475139399, 0.901206599700221, 0.938186421066386, 0.817601118830569, 
0.998879888878252, 0.612855023767725, 0.66661039116652, 0.780886797440356, 
0.416894974234899, 0.516028546997213, 0.228493779760707, 0.180492518880357, 
0.0872574331179239, 0.0562605389443052, 0.92828268169163, 0.908299573720351, 
0.313083322211844, 0.317939934294433, 0.833270457777705, 0.944814684090358, 
0.516292344139557, 0.860624653168591, 0.815580971336458, 0.946932968305583, 
0.133250948190429, 0.692126111495591, 0.00450343070881709, 0.776433481915768, 
0.642709887325145, 0.0467694562058146, 0.328734895196091, 0.316914538539486, 
0.631060254330745, 0.306871357989628, 0.194087017118568, 0.985472752557697, 
0.428587799376777, 0.00537361261016367, 0.929737213630118, 0.178166777298782, 
0.458101672143506, 0.936443042786035, 0.604477797854701, 0.27558910997039, 
0.594629580959861, 0.516862946229946, 0.334134868427636, 0.35282462084093, 
0.726048651254153, 0.161202150849049, 0.769852810743947, 0.170122621575997, 
0.708418305775943, 0.374084046943861, 0.656103357314548), ENET_WinP = c(0.376797188438971, 
0.440082695690767, 0.560426153017069, 0.884087023955913, 0.320283166512571, 
0.598969241889637, 0.874791139513396, 0.403175783073465, 0.353991872837964, 
0.592363070905669, 0.386467280638169, 0.83094700743756, 0.820185487372966, 
0.800519723084049, 0.260872486760217, 0.201048171817858, 0.19645691107559, 
0.930233435950361, 0.728311181937606, 0.818296180693016, 0.231575380948394, 
0.750337750505728, 0.580894416487517, 0.0269090570776034, 0.510045476179919, 
0.519527872225584, 0.958485196488128, 0.901788608954781, 0.692735158264612, 
0.661114271923073, 0.530615815921976, 0.422829277192182, 0.210410591821317, 
0.0667469302069553, 0.356411085751059, 0.106243550716451, 0.0966124007470056, 
0.252437838222532, 0.582525442807074, 0.575721333894169, 0.471326790899397, 
0.189660715838895, 0.229731603732155, 0.678046777175715, 0.784881225360488, 
0.972792580610392, 0.374258819536079, 0.714300690694055, 0.438646274627636, 
0.034421452176977, 0.242648781298251, 0.627506222893452, 0.276326191040387, 
0.507484881023458, 0.0266678979491796, 0.64254544706957, 0.38759581458661, 
0.195993496042201, 0.772067933960612, 0.490837360249447, 0.0926671344008307, 
0.522179263220861, 0.772178015111987, 0.503638988702346, 0.94633126162395, 
0.22168948475807, 0.533719965320603, 0.905420058401729, 0.200220652884564, 
0.0183702982451034, 0.368865442768652, 0.898313017742509, 0.423437627329978, 
0.866370664887362, 0.228047803289617, 0.224019495700614, 0.358686951797117, 
0.876472867126893, 0.460264495428769, 0.917804441107961, 0.047160286658086, 
0.584131500836106, 0.197491826799768, 0.26336310487536, 0.831135352408695, 
0.33925905484227, 0.324609712686945, 0.1523567520872, 0.23537965419749, 
0.65313971868625, 0.841473584513374, 0.575787196328203, 0.969116667478611, 
0.887096000069419, 0.468617730179891, 0.707310991502054, 0.808830763749894, 
0.965516874651877, 0.379716995266897, 0.238551839508423), Actual_Result = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Each of the 7 columns to the left represent the probability that the Actual_Result column is a 1. I'm trying to figure out which model or combination of models is best based on their performance when the _WinP value is greater than 0.5238. Few Examples from the data: SVM_WinP > 0.5238 = 0.58 accurate, SVM_WinP >0.5238 & Boosted_WinP>0.5238 = 0.54545 accurate, Boosted_WinP > 0.5238 & PLS_WinP > 0.5238 & LR_WinP >0.5238 = 0.3636 accurate. With there being 6 different columns there will be 63 different combinations that I could use. I know how to code each one individually, but there's gotta be a better way to loop through all of these and pull the best one without coding 61 different lines of code (one for each combo). Really appreciate your guys help on this.

**EDIT 1**
A sample of the ending result would hopefully be the following (real result will obviously have 63 rows rather than 3):

```
structure(list(Models = c("SVM_WinP", "SVM_WinP,Boosted_WinP", 
"Boosted_WinP,PLS_WinP,LR_WinP"), ATS = c(0.58, 0.54545, 0.3636
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Couple of notes, I have created all of the possible groups that need to be accounted for with the following code:

```
groupNames <- names(Sample_Data)[1:6]
myGroups <- Map(combn, 
                list(groupNames), 
                seq_along(groupNames),
                simplify = FALSE) %>%
  unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

I just don't know how to loop through these and calculate the ATS. ATS is just going to equal the sum of the Actual Result column divided by the length of that column. For Example, the first row of the desired result is for the SVM_WinP column only. When that column is filtered for greater than 0.5238, there is 50 rows, and 29 of them are 1. Thus, the ATS is 29/50 = 0.58.

Comment: Hi @Lcsballer1, I'd like to try to help answer your question, but I'm having trouble imagining what the result looks like. Maybe you could share how you would "code each one individually"?

Comment: Hey @Skaqqs, thank you so much for your help! I have updated the question above to hopefully account for your question. Let me know what else you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very intriguing question and well supported with data and example code. Thanks very much for that. Here's my approach, step by step, and a function that combines each step at the bottom.

```
# Define variables
vars <- setdiff(names(dat), "Actual_Result")
head(vars)
#> [1] "SVM_WinP"     "Boosted_WinP" "PLS_WinP"     "LR_WinP"      "Cubist_WinP" 
#> [6] "ENET_WinP"

# Define all combinations of variables
x <- expand.grid(vars, vars)
head(x)
#>           Var1     Var2
#> 1     SVM_WinP SVM_WinP
#> 2 Boosted_WinP SVM_WinP
#> 3     PLS_WinP SVM_WinP
#> 4      LR_WinP SVM_WinP
#> 5  Cubist_WinP SVM_WinP
#> 6    ENET_WinP SVM_WinP

# Get all cases where each var in a pair is greater than some
# performance threshold y
y <- 0.5238
which(dat$SVM_WinP > y & dat$Boosted_WinP > y,)
#>  [1]  1  3  7 11 14 16 17 18 24 27 28 30 31 33 42 44 46 55 59 63 64 65 70 71 75
#> [26] 76 77 79 80 81 85 87 99

# Get the "Actual_Result" for each case
dat[which(dat$SVM_WinP > y & dat$Boosted_WinP > y,),"Actual_Result"]
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1

# Get percent success in "Actual_Result"
mean(dat[which(dat$SVM_WinP > y & dat$Boosted_WinP > y,),"Actual_Result"])
#> [1] 0.5454545

# Where x is a pair of variables and y is a performance threshold
lcs_combo <- function(x, dat, y){
  var1 <- x[[1]]
  var2 <- x[[2]]
  ATS <- mean(dat[which(dat[,var1] > y & dat[,var2] > y),"Actual_Result"])
  return(c(var1 = paste(var1), var2 = paste(var2), ATS))
}

# Result for one pair of values
lcs_combo(x[5,], dat, 0.5238)
#>      var1          var2       ATS                
#> [1,] "Cubist_WinP" "SVM_WinP" "0.473684210526316"

# Apply over all combinations of values
apply(X = x, MARGIN = 1, FUN = lcs_combo, dat, 0.5238)
#>      [,1]       [,2]                [,3]                [,4]               
#> [1,] "SVM_WinP" "Boosted_WinP"      "PLS_WinP"          "LR_WinP"          
#> [2,] "SVM_WinP" "SVM_WinP"          "SVM_WinP"          "SVM_WinP"         
#> [3,] "0.58"     "0.545454545454545" "0.444444444444444" "0.538461538461538"
```

To format the result from `apply()` into a format more similar to what you have in the edit of your question, wrap it in `t()`.

edit: Accommodate any number of elements in each group

```
y <- 0.5238 
out <- c()
for(i in 1:length(myGroups)){
  groups <- myGroups[[i]]
  # rowSums() fails when there's only one group
  if(length(groups) == 1){
    ATS <- mean(dat[which(dat[,groups] > y),"Actual_Result"])
  } else{
    ATS <- mean(dat[rowSums(dat[,groups] > y) == length(groups),"Actual_Result"])
  }
  out <- rbind(out, c(paste(groups, collapse=","), ATS))
}
out
```

Comment: Hey @Skaqqs, this is awesome, this is so close to what I'm needing. I noticed it's only for all 2 variable combinations. I'm actually needing it for all possible combinations (1,2,3,4,5,6). There is 63 different combinations of the 6 columns so I would expect the final result to be 63 lines long each with an ATS. Is this something you can help with? Thank you so much again for all your help!

Comment: No problem, I'd be happy to update my answer. Is it all combinations of variables where all variables > performance threshold?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right

Comment: Please take a look at the edit in my answer; I believe this is what you are looking for. Note that in cases where not all elements in myGroups is > performance, NaN is returned.

Comment: This worked perfectly @Skaqqs! Thank you so much again, this was a MASSIVE help to me.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck!