# Changing data format for survival analysis in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have collected data on seed germination in batches of 25 seeds, and recorded the data by making rows for each batch, and columns for each day - listing the number of seeds germinated in that batch per day. The raw data looks like this, with the "Dx" columns representing the consecutive days since the trial started:

[Raw Germination Timing Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mEw3.png)

In order to increase statistical power when creating linear models for this project, I wrote a function to split these batches into rows for each individual seed, with a binary 0/1 outcome corresponding to not germinated / germinated. I then used a GLM with log link function to predict probability of success in a binary way. The function for making the data binary, and the resulting data looks like this:
[Raw to Binary Data Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvQ03.png)

[Resulting Binary (Germ/No Germ) Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN28D.png)

But I now want to perform a survival analysis to look at how the factors contribute to changes in timing / overall success of germination. I have an idea of the format my data needs to be in for the survival analysis, and unless I am mistaken, I could use this binary data format if I only had a column specifying the day of germination. If anyone is able to help me alter my binary data function to achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: I'd like to try to help answer your question, but I won't be able to give specific advice unless you are able to share your data in a way where I can test ideas on my machine (good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179580/which-column-combination-is-best-r/69224421#69224421). General advice: get number of germinations for each day for each ID+Rep from `datasheet` and distribute the days among the seeds in `germdatabinary` using simple row indexing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.